# Correlators of Trace Operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory

How do I calculate correlators of trace operators? E.g. in $\cal{N}=4$ SYM in 4D we have operators like $Tr(\phi^i)$, where $\phi^i$ is one of the scalars. If I wanted to calculate something like $\langle Tr(\phi^i)Tr\phi^j\rangle$, how would I do so given the associated propagators?